# problem trying to log in after update

Tags: login, debugging

after an update I can't pass the log in with my user, I log in as guest and the error "no session for pid 2149" apears and I cant really use it either; searched for solutions and it apears to be a bug but I cant try out solutions as I cant access terminal. Accessing terminal from log in screen will not recognice my password...

Any ideas on how to solve this?